# Unknown issue with image refinement process

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

As introduced in this [work](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231218307033) ([code](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1NFboaeuuBph_QQGgXuIcaA)), the following code sould refine an image (i.e. a gray scale saliency map).

**Refinement Function:**

```
function sal = Refinement(y, dim)
th_2 = graythresh(y);
if dim == 1
    sal = y;

    sal(y<th_2) = 10*(y(y < th_2))/th_2 - 10;
    sal(y>=th_2) = 10*(y(y >= th_2) - th_2)/(1-th_2);
    sal = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-sal)) + y;
    sal = normalization(sal, 0);
elseif dim == 2
    [r, c] = size(y);
    y_col = reshape(y,[1 r*c]);
    sal_col = y_col;
    sal_col(y_col<th_2) = 10*(y_col(y_col < th_2))/th_2 - 10;
    sal_col(y_col>=th_2) = 10*(y_col(y_col >= th_2) - th_2)/(1-th_2);
    sal_col = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-sal_col)) + y_col;
    sal = reshape(sal_col, [r c]);
end
end
```

**normalization function:**

```
function matrix = normalization(mat, flag)
 % INPUT : 
 %         flag:  1 denotes that the mat is a 3-d matrix;
 %                0 denotes that the mat is a matrix;
 %         
 if flag ~= 0
dim = size(mat,3);
matrix = mat;
for i = 1:dim
   matrix(:,:,i) = ( mat(:,:,i) - min(min(mat(:,:,i)))) / ( max(max(mat(:,:,i))) - min(min( mat(:,:,i))) + eps);
end
else
     matrix = ( mat - min(min(mat)))/( max(max(mat)) - min(min(mat)) + eps);
end
```

However, after applying the function values of the image matrix will be changed, the result remains the same as the image before the refinement.

Is there a conceptual error with that or the implementation failed?

P.S. The input image (saliency map) for refinery is something like below. in the refined saliency map, the foreground (satrfish in this image) should stand out(becomes homogeneously white as possible) and the background noise should be removed (becomes homogenously black as possible):

[image]

Comment: In the paper they used an RGB's images as starting points, the image you attached is the input or the output? What behaviour do you desire its not clear from the question?

Comment: @DavidS, The first part of the code produces a saliency map (the attached image) from the input image and the refinement process should improve the saliency map. Specifically, in the refined saliency map, the foreground (satrfish in this image) should stand out(becomes homogeneously white as possible) and the background  noise should be removed (becomes homogenously black as possible).